# How do I add a Foreign Key Field to a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

What I would like to do is to display a single form that lets the user:

- Enter a document title (from `Document` model)
- Select one of their `user_defined_code` choices from a drop down list (populated by the `UserDefinedCode` model)
- Type in a `unique_code` (stored in the `Code` model)

I'm not sure how to go about displaying the fields for the foreign key relationships in a form. I know in a view you can use document.code_set (for example) to access the related objects for the current `document` object, but I'm not sure how to apply this to a ModelForm.

My model:

```
class UserDefinedCode(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Code(models.Model):
    user_defined_code = models.ForeignKey(UserDefinedCode)
    unique_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    code = models.ForeignKey(Code)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My ModelForm

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In regards to displaying a foreign key field in a form you can use the [**`forms.ModelChoiceField`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) and pass it a queryset.

so, forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user','')
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_defined_code']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserDefinedCode.objects.filter(owner=user))
```

views.py:

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method=='post':
        form=DocumentForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            selected_user_defined_code = form.cleaned_data.get('user_defined_code')
            #do stuff here
    else:
        form=DocumentForm(user=request.user)

    context = { 'form':form, }

    return render_to_response('sometemplate.html', context, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

from your question:

> I know in a view you can use
>   document.code_set (for example) to
>   access the related objects for the
>   current document object, but I'm not
>   sure how to apply this to a ModelForm.

Actually, your `Document` objects wouldn't have a `.code_set` since the FK relationship is defined in your documents model. It is defining a many to one relationship to `Code`, which means there can be many `Document` objects per `Code` object, not the other way around. Your `Code` objects would have a `.document_set`. What you can do from the document object is access which `Code` it is related to using `document.code`.

**edit:** I think this will do what you are looking for. (untested)

forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ('code',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user','')
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_defined_code']=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=UserDefinedCode.objects.filter(owner=user))
        self.fields['unique_code']=forms.CharField(max_length=15)
```

views.py:

```
def someview(request):
    if request.method=='post':
        form=DocumentForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            uniquecode = form.cleaned_data.get('unique_code')
            user_defined_code = form.cleaned_data.get('user_defined_code')
            doc_code = Code(user_defined_code=user_defined_code, code=uniquecode)
            doc_code.save()
            doc = form.save(commit=False)
            doc.code = doc_code
            doc.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        form=DocumentForm(user=request.user)

    context = { 'form':form, }

    return render_to_response('sometemplate.html', context, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

actually you probably want to use get_or_create when creating your Code object instead of this.

```
doc_code = Code(user_defined_code=user_defined_code, code=uniquecode)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read up on the docs for ModelChoiceField and it makes sense now. Do you know how I would display the CharField (third bullet point in my question) for the `unique_code` field? I've thinned out my models a little to make them easier to read, but basically I have a document that is assigned a computer-generated, unique document code. Each user can create a separate user code that is attached as a prefix to the document code for all documents they own, hence the reason for the multiple models.

Comment: There are some other things to know like pre-fill widget with value (it's in the view via `get_initial()`)

Comment: Assigning to `self.fields['user_defined_code']` in `__init__` is ugly, but usually not avoidable: It would be nicer to declare `user_defined_code = ModelChoiceField(...)` as a class attribute, but that is rarely possible, because the `queryset` argument will usually require something that is not available at form-class declaration time.