# How to store request.POST values in database with Django?

Tags: python, django, sms, twilio

I'm trying to store the messages sent to Twilio number and since they're sent as HTTP request, I thought I could get the parameters values with request.POST but how can I save these values and store them in a database for retrieval later? Here's the code I've come up with but it doesn't work.

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def incoming(request):
    from_ = request.POST.get('From')
    body_ = request.POST.get('Body')
    to_ = request.POST.get('To')
    m = Message.objects.create(sentfrom=from_, content=body_, to=to_)
    m.save()
    twiml = '<Response><Message>Hi</Message></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(twiml, content_type='text/xml')
```

The code work when I delete all the request.POST and database query

```
@csrf_exempt
def incoming(request):
    twiml = '<Response><Message>Hi</Message></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(twiml, content_type='text/xml')
```

Here is the Message model from models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    to = models.ForeignKey(phoneNumber, null=True)
    sentfrom = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way to save is to have a model form and call is_valid and save method on them. Using request.POST is not advised, as it does not validate data. Something like below:

```
from django import forms
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Message
      fields = '__all__'
```

and in your view call the MessageForm save method to save. Also please note that 'to' field is a foreign key, it may be worth having look at [How do I add a Foreign Key Field to a ModelForm in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django)

Comment: This sounds right, especially if the POST payload is predictable (you know what fields you're getting back). I would create a Model to store this information and a ModelForm to validate/clean. You could skip the Model and simply define a Form, too if you're storing this information elsewhere.