# Django input username in charfield

Tags: django

I have this form where you input a username into a charfield, the model is as follow:

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sender = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    receiver = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['sender', 'receiver', 'message']
        labels = {
            'receiver': 'Message to',
        }
```

Error

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot assign "'testuser'": "Message.receiver" must be a "User" instance.
```

So basically I want users to input the username into the CharField, but it obviously complains about the field not accepting text, since it only accepts a User instance. What is the best way to go about this? I was thinking about overriding either the `save()` or `post()` to pass the text from the field and get the user from the queryset (`User.objects.get(username=receiver)`) but i'm not sure how to implement this. Anyone got a suggestion for this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: cofused at your question May this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another field in the forms to enter the username and make the sender field to hidden input , while validating the form make the set the sender to User instance using the clean_sender method:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In forms.py :

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sender = forms.HiddenInput()        
    receiver = forms.HiddenInput()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender_username = forms.CharField(max_length =255, verbose_name = "Sender")
    receiver_username = forms.CharField(max_length =255, verbose_name = "Receiver")

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
           'receiver': 'Message to',
        }

    def clean_sender(self):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data.get('sender_username'))


    def clean_sender(self):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data.get('receiver_username'))
```

By adding additional fields you can take the username as input and then get the appropriate user instances while you  validate the form.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) is the link to clean individual field in a form before saving.