# Django simple queryset in form field

Tags: python, django, forms

I couldn't find any solution in previous answers so i'm here asking how to register the result of a form field made by a queryset. Maybe i'm doing wrong something simple here how ever my model are:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Contatto(models.Model):
    contatto_choice =  models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contatto
        fields = ['contatto_choice', 'phone_number','email','text']
```

My forms.py is:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contatto_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Choice.objects.all())
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, max_length=500)
```

and my views is:

```
def contatti(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contatto = Contatto()
            contatto.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            contatto.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            contatto.text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            contatto.contatto_choice = form.cleaned_data['contatto_choice']
            contatto.save()
            recipients = ['cercaservizi@gmail.com']
            send_mail("Contatto Cercaservizi", contatto.phone_number+' '+contatto.email+' '+contatto.text,contatto.email, recipients)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

The view of the submitted form complains about the fact that a contatto_choice should be an instance of a choice i cannot find any tutorial about how to solve this. If you could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do have two different `ContactForm`s?

Comment: I tought this was the way to do it...

Comment: How would you do it differently?

Comment: Use the one in `forms.py` and maybe a little tweak. See [How do I add a Foreign Key Field to a ModelForm in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit Your ContactForm

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):    
    contatto_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Choice.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Contatto
        fields = ['contatto_choice', 'phone_number','email','text']
```

and you will not need other form