# django adding values to foerignkey field

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple application which requires each employee can have multiple files, so i created two models one is Employee and the other one is Files

```
class Files(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files')

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    cv = models.ForeignKey(
        Files, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when i try to upload a file it gives me an error.

```
Cannot assign "'list-employees.png'": "Employee.cv" must be a "Files" instance.

Exception Type:     ValueError
```

Comment: I think you are trying to assign the file uploaded to the employee instance directly.. based on your model, you should first create a `Files` instance with the file and then assign the `Files` instance to employee.cv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it upside down:

```
class Files(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

You can access the employee files calling `my_employee.files`

Then, you will need to update your form (assuming you are using one), to deal with the relation. [Here you can see how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django)