# Fill field with data from DB for validation on django-admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm working with django and it's powerful administrator.

It's simple. I have a field that needs to be filled with the contents of database for validation.

Example: 
The field is Name. I want the field to make itself a deployable list with all the names contained in the DB.

If the field is Name, the user should see a deployable list with "John", "Edward", "Joshua"... Because those have been stored in the db.

Comment: Do you just want a ForeignKey?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a Foreign Key Field to a ModelForm in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with a ChoiceField, give it a try and if you cannot solve it I will gadly help you.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield