# Django IntegrityError - NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

The error I am facing says that I am tring to submit a form with empty required field.

### Error

[image: Error]

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: bug_report_bug.project_id
```

---

### My Code:-

The thing I am trying to do is enable users report bugs for any of a project. So the user clicks on a project and then gets a bug report form where he/she can report the bug. Every bug is connected to its project.

#### Models.py

```py
class Bug(models.Model):
    reported_by: models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bug_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    bug_description = models.TextField()
    screenshot = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='Bug_Reports')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'Project: {}\nBug: {}'.format(self.project.title, self.bug_title)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("bugReport", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

#### Forms.py

```py
class BugReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bug
        fields = ('bug_title', 'bug_description', 'screenshot')
```

#### Views.py

```py
def bug_register(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BugReportForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.project = Project.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
            form.user = request.user
            print(form.project.id)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Thankyou for Reporting! We will review your issue and revert back soon,')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, f'Please fill all the mandatory fields!')
    else:
        form = BugReportForm()
    return render(request, 'bug_report/report.html', {'form': form})
```

As you can see I am sending id of project in URL and then accepting it in views and querying project class to get the object. I am not able to debugg where am I lacking.

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/bugreport/1/`

> The error says to fill a field I am unable understand as I have not made it. Also while using admin dashboard form I am able to report any bug there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a Foreign Key Field to a ModelForm in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django)

Comment: @AnubhavUjjawal not completely I knew the concept of connecting models but the problem is to somehow register my bugs using project Id due to which I am getting errors.

Comment: You might want to change `project ` to `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField`, as one project can have many bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across such issue, after searching extensively on SO, DRF official documentation here and other forums, I saw a simple comment that suggested dropping the entire migrations folder and make the migrations again.
Here is a simple command to remove migration folder in your project:

> ```
> rm -f db.sqlite3
> rm -r <your_app_name>/migrations
> python manage.py makemigrations <your_app_name>
> python manage.py migrate
> ```

See the official documentation of djanjo-rest-framework [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#tutorial-4-authentication-permissions)

I hope this helps someone some day.

Answer (score 1):

The following links contain documentation and code examples on how to add a foreign key field to a django form:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5708772/13499618
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

You would basically use a `django.forms.ModelChoiceField` to allow your users to select a  which will render as a `select` dropdown in HTML by default. Then, on submit, the form data will be sent accordingly to the backend with the respective id of the `Project` in the `BugForm`, and `form.save()` will work.

Comment: I looked up to the documentation and I hope that I have not messed up whhile connecting these models. The main issue if you see the wrror above is Django is asking me to fill a field in the form that don't exist and is not even dreated by me.

Comment: You have to add a `Project` field in your form, which will be a `django.forms.ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: yes, that is working perfectly but what if I want to fix the value of project. What I mean is I am making an app similar to Github Issue feature. I guess its now understood what I want to accomplish. Only after selecting a project you can proceed to report a bug about it so it will make no sense to give user a form where he needs to select the project again.

Comment: Make the project a hidden field in your form then. And pass the id of your project as initial value to your form.
https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/eMUuQ9JZ45g.

Comment: did the same thing passed project id through URL but still not working

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same problem which was solve by adding `null=True` to the field shown on the debug message.