# Django DatField returns null value every time I register information

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that registers a project information which have `start date` and `end date` but when I submit those information, the value of `start date` and `end date` is `null` their value never saved to the database.
Here is my model.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, related_name='employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=PROJECT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=COMING_STATUS, null=True, blank=True
    )
    start_date = models.DateField( null=False)
    end_date = models.DateField( null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

Here is the list of project data

```
 {
        "id": 1,
        "created_by": "Teshome",
        "project_name": "Teshome",
        "status": "Coming",
        "start_date": null,
        "end_date": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-15T12:16:31.045887Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-15T12:16:31.045887Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "created_by": "Teshome",
        "project_name": "Babi",
        "status": "Ended",
        "start_date": null,
        "end_date": null,
        "created_at": "2022-04-15T12:30:03.332208Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-15T12:30:03.332208Z"
    },
```

Here is the Django admin interface where I register project information.
[image]
I did not use any frontend framework to register project information I just did it from Django Admin.

How can I solve this Isuue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question and share how admin page looks like just before saving changes?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak I added admin page. Can you look at it and give me your suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that all migrations are applied? Try running `python manage.py makemigrations` and then the same, but with `migrate`. And reload the admin page.

Comment: @BartoszStasiak I did but it I got `null` value anyway.

Comment: With your current setup it shouldn't be even possible to have `null` saved in those field in DB :/ It should throw `is not none contrain` error... I will open a chat and see if we can find what is an issue

Comment: @BartoszStasiak you are right, when I post with json format it returns `NOT NULL constraint failed: projects_project.created_by_id` . What can I do to solve this?

Comment: This error means that you are trying to save models with empty fields. In this case it was `created_by` field. Where are you having post request with this json?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243933/discussion-between-bartosz-stasiak-and-tesh-aych).

Comment: I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862331/18330318 and it works

Comment: Ow ok. So I was on the right track with running migrations again :) I'm glad that you found solutions to this