# Django two models on one form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Thanks in advance.  This is my first question on StackOverflow.  I am a newbie to Django and I'm trying to create an inventory checklist for someone to quickly look at the inventory and place a number in the count column.  What I am missing is how to link the count field to the item_name (iterate the count field with the item_name.  When I type in values and submit it makes each count field equal to the first count field.  Please see attachments of screenshots.

***Here is my models.py***

```
class InventoryItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class InventoryChecklist(models.Model):
    count = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    item = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

***forms.py***

```
class InventoryCheck(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InventoryChecklist
        fields = '__all__'
```

***views.py***

```
def DailyCount(request):
    items = InventoryItem.objects.all()
        
    form = InventoryCheck
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InventoryCheck(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/')

    context = {'items':items, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'checklist/dailycount.html', context)
```

***template***

```
<table class="table table-sm">
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                    <th>Date</th>  
                </tr>
            <form action="" method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}

                    {% for item in items %}
                            
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ item.item_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form.count }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    {% endfor %}
                    <input type="submit" name="Save" /> 
            </form>

            </table>
```

[rendered template before submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2tJB.png)
[rendered template after submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw0w4.png)

Comment: [Look here if this solves your purpose.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django)

Comment: I don't believe that is the answer.  I am attempting to update several records at one time in a table.  I have the item_name field with the static data and I want to update the quantity of all of those items in the count field.

Answer (score 0):

`form = InventoryCheck` is passing in the class, but not an initialized object. Your form is not really... iterable (i.e. when you're doing `form.count`)? Do you mean to do `item.count`?

Edit: since you're grabbing all items, you should instead do:

```
items = InventoryChecklist.objects.all()
```

and then work off that. That way, in your template, you can do:

```
{{ item.item.item_name }}
{{ item.count }}
```

Comment: Right.  I'm not sure how to make the form field count follow the item_name field as I am iterating through that field so I can update all of the counts of each item_name in one table.  I apologize if I am not saying it in a manner that can be understood.

Comment: Don't sweat it. Lemme update my answer. I can see the issue now.

Comment: Try the new edit. I based it off your current query which is getting all InventoryItem objects when you can instead get InventoryChecklist instead and grab the item via FK.

Comment: How would I enter a value if I use item.count? Do I need the form?

Comment: The point is that your form should have nothing to do with this? Your form is meant to update or create an item.